# NullPointerException in app with AdMob whenever activity starts

Tags: android, admob

I am getting such error after lunching android application with AdMob added, despite that fact the adverts are displaying properly, i would like to fix it... Can You help?

```
08-03 14:47:28.296: E/Ads(3247): An error occurred while destroying an AdWebView:
08-03 14:47:28.296: E/Ads(3247): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-03 14:47:28.296: E/Ads(3247):    at android.webkit.WebView.setWebViewClient(WebView.java:5084)
08-03 14:47:28.296: E/Ads(3247):    at com.google.ads.internal.AdWebView.destroy(SourceFile:252)
08-03 14:47:28.296: E/Ads(3247):    at com.google.ads.internal.c$e.run(SourceFile:191)
08-03 14:47:28.296: E/Ads(3247):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
08-03 14:47:28.296: E/Ads(3247):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-03 14:47:28.296: E/Ads(3247):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-03 14:47:28.296: E/Ads(3247):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
08-03 14:47:28.296: E/Ads(3247):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-03 14:47:28.296: E/Ads(3247):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-03 14:47:28.296: E/Ads(3247):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
08-03 14:47:28.296: E/Ads(3247):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
08-03 14:47:28.296: E/Ads(3247):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code:

inside oncreate():

> ```
>       // Create the adView            
>       adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER,
>       ADMOB_UNIT_ID);
>
>       // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it’s been given            // the
>       attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"          RelativeLayout layout =
>       (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_relative_layout);
>
>       // Add the adView to it             layout.addView(adView);
>
>       AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
>
>       if (DebugIndicator.DEBUG) {
>           adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR); // Emulator
>           adRequest.addTestDevice(deviceid); // Test Android Device
>           adRequest.addTestDevice("c16079314a5512f"); // Test Android
>                                                       // Device
>           adRequest.addTestDevice("2cf3765d"); // Test Android Device
>           adRequest.addTestDevice("FC4AA4F51610C2029A55E3E9A323617A");            }
>
>       // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
>       adView.loadAd(adRequest);
> ```

also to activity added:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (adView != null) {
        adView.destroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an Android WebView error crash that the AdMob SDK is catching and logging as an error.  It should be logged as a warning.  It does not crash the app, and should not affect ad reloads.

Comment: for me, it crashes the app.